# How to multiply between the columns of different rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Here is the equation. Example

```
Numbers     | Date      | Mean
1000        |12/1/2018  | 1
1002        |12/2/2018  | 0
1003        |12/3/2018  | 0.5
 0          |12/4/2018  | 0.6
 0          |12/5/2018  | 0.4
 0          |12/6/2018  |0.1
 0          |12/7/2018  | -0.7
 0          |12/8/2018  | 0.2
 0          |12/9/2018  | -0.1
```

Here what I want

```
|Numbers | Date      | Mean | Multiplication |
| ------ |-----------|------|----------------|
|1000    | 12/1/2018 | 1    | 1000           |
|1002    | 12/2/2018 | 0    | 0*1000= 0      |
|1003    | 12/3/2018 | 0.5  | 0.5*1002=501   |
|0       | 12/4/2018 | 0.6  | 1003*0.6=601.8 |
|0       | 12/5/208  | 0.4  | 601.8*0.4
|0       | 12/6/2018 | 0.1  | 601.8*0.4*0.1  |
|0       |12/7/2018  | -0.7 |601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7| 
 0       |12/8/2018  | 0.2  |601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7*0.2
 0       |12/9/2018  | -0.1 |601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7*0.2*-0.1
```

the data is already in the data-frame and I am using pandas functions

Comment: Your title and your final output is not clear.Both are contradicting.Please Re-check and then post again.

Comment: @Parth Dhir, your previous title was more meaningful where you said "How to multiply the 3rd column of the 2nd row with the 1st column of the 1st row. You can't have 1000 as the value for the first row column Multiplication. It is breaking the pattern.

Comment: @Parth Dhir, you changed the basic concept of your question. I will remove my answer and post it once you are done.

Comment: @Raj006 sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Parth Dhir, you need to explain in words what you are trying to achieve for the Multiplication column. I started creating an answer for your changed question, and you changed the requirements yet again. Please, edit the post after you are clear about what you want.

Comment: Whenever there is a 0 in Number column, It should take previous multiplication column value and multiple with mean to give the result

Comment: @ParthDhir, I used the latest requirements and posted the answer. Please, mark it as answer and upvote if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @ParthDhir, just saw that you mentioned that your data is in the panda data frame. Modified my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel Labbe answered for the initial requirements, and it was correct. +1 to him for shift() method. Then, user requirements changed. So, here is my answer for the latest requirements.

```
#import pandas for managing data with dataframe
import pandas as pd
#import tabulate to print your data frame as table
from tabulate import tabulate
#Create a data dictionary
myData={'Numbers':[1000,1002,1003,0,0,0,0,0,0],'Date':['12/1/2018','12/2/2018','12/3/2018','12/4/2018','12/5/2018','12/6/2018','12/7/2018','12/8/2018','12/9/2018'],'Mean':[1,0,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.1,-0.7,0.2,-0.1]}
#Create a data frame from the data dictionary using pandas. User mentioned that the data is already in the
#pandas data frame
myDataFrame=pd.DataFrame(myData)
#Print your final table (just pretty print)
print(tabulate(myDataFrame, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
#Declare a list
MultiplicationList=[]
#Declare a constant
StorePreviousValue=0
for i in range(0,len(myDataFrame['Numbers'])):
    #If it is the first row then use the Number
    if i==0:
        #Append the value to the list
        MultiplicationList.append(myDataFrame['Numbers'][i])
    else:
        #If it is not the first row, and the value in the first column of the previous row is '0'
        #multiply Mean with the previous multiplication result
        if myDataFrame['Numbers'][i-1]==0:
            StorePreviousValue=StorePreviousValue*myDataFrame['Mean'][i]
        #If it is not the first row, and the value in the first column of the previous row is not '0'
        #(should probably say greate than '0', but the question is not clear about that), then 
        #multiply Mean with the Number in the first column of the previous row
        else:
            StorePreviousValue=myDataFrame['Numbers'][i-1]*myDataFrame['Mean'][i]
        #Append the value to the list
        MultiplicationList.append(StorePreviousValue)
#Create a new column in the data frame and pass the list as the value
myDataFrame['Multiplication']=MultiplicationList
#Print your final table (just pretty print)
print(tabulate(myDataFrame, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Here is the output

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|    |   Numbers | Date      |   Mean |
|----+-----------+-----------+--------|
|  0 |      1000 | 12/1/2018 |    1   |
|  1 |      1002 | 12/2/2018 |    0   |
|  2 |      1003 | 12/3/2018 |    0.5 |
|  3 |         0 | 12/4/2018 |    0.6 |
|  4 |         0 | 12/5/2018 |    0.4 |
|  5 |         0 | 12/6/2018 |    0.1 |
|  6 |         0 | 12/7/2018 |   -0.7 |
|  7 |         0 | 12/8/2018 |    0.2 |
|  8 |         0 | 12/9/2018 |   -0.1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+------------------+
|    |   Numbers | Date      |   Mean |   Multiplication |
|----+-----------+-----------+--------+------------------|
|  0 |      1000 | 12/1/2018 |    1   |      1000        |
|  1 |      1002 | 12/2/2018 |    0   |         0        |
|  2 |      1003 | 12/3/2018 |    0.5 |       501        |
|  3 |         0 | 12/4/2018 |    0.6 |       601.8      |
|  4 |         0 | 12/5/2018 |    0.4 |       240.72     |
|  5 |         0 | 12/6/2018 |    0.1 |        24.072    |
|  6 |         0 | 12/7/2018 |   -0.7 |       -16.8504   |
|  7 |         0 | 12/8/2018 |    0.2 |        -3.37008  |
|  8 |         0 | 12/9/2018 |   -0.1 |         0.337008 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+------------------+
```

If you don't have pandas or tabulate, please install using
pip install pandas
pip install tabulate

If you are not familiar with pip, google for it.
This answer is assuming that you know how to read from a file and create your data dictionary. If you don't that will be another question to ask.

Comment: you have done a for loop using mydata which is a dictionary. What if, we do for loop on myInitialDataFrame?

Comment: thanks for the help. Sorry, I am editing my requirement again and again. Just trying to learn the things.

lets suppose mean is -0.7 in the next row. What shall be need to add then?

Comment: @ParthDhir, added more data you updated your question with.

Comment: What if I want to use iloc function not loc?. I am having trouble using loc function

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Pandas dataframe, you can use the [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method:

```
df['Multiplication'] = df.Mean * df.Numbers.shift(1)
df.loc[0, 'Multiplication'] = df.Numbers[0]
for i in range(len(df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0])):
    df.loc[df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].index, 'Multiplication'] = df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].Mean.values * df[df.index.isin(df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].index-1)].Multiplication.values
```

With the following output:

[image]

The first row you don't have both numbers to multiply, so the update value is made after the multiplication.

Now meeting the requirement of the zero number values.

Breaking down a little bit the code, as @Raj006 suggestd:

```
# return just the rows that match the condition (Numbers column 0 for the row before)
df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].index

# update the values for the column Multiplication with the matching rows
df.loc[df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].index, 'Multiplication']

# the value to be update is the [Mean value for the matching rows] * [rows before the matching Multiplication value]
df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].Mean.values * df[df.index.isin(df[df.Numbers.shift(1) == 0].index-1)].Multiplication.values
```

Edit:
I had to use a for loop, unfortunately, to run as many times as matching rows, once the calculation depends on the calculation before.

Comment: thanks for the help. Sorry, I am editing my requirement again and again. Just trying to learn the things. lets suppose mean is -0.7 in the next row. What shall be need to add in the code then?

Comment: The code supposed to be generic, and works no matter the data you have considering the constraints.

Comment: if I multiple 420 while is last row of multiplication column with a mean of -0.7. What do you think the result should be? -294?
what if the 420 is dollar amount not just the numbers.

Comment: Please, add the data to the question so I can test it.

Comment: @ParthDhir The last three values with the new dataset were -16.850400, -3.370080 and 0.337008. Exactly what you expected, considering: -16.8504=601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7
-3.37008=601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7*0.2
0.337008=601.8*0.4*0.1*-0.7*0.2*-0.1

Comment: Please upvote the answer and selected it as correct. :)

Comment: i think, if there is any term, it should first subtract with 1 and then multiply with the previous number. 
like suppose previous Number is 420 and now mean is -0.9. Then 1-0.9=0.1 and then multiple by 420. So the answer would be 4.2 i guess, if i am not wrong.

Comment: and even for positive mean. I guess 1+mean should be there. Like if it is 0.4 mean. It should be 1+0.4=1.04 and then multiple by previous Number.

Comment: Can you please let me know?

Comment: Yes, but I have just left the office. I will back to this later today or tomorrow, ok?

Comment: HI, What if I want to use iloc function, not loc . Having little problem using loc function. Can you please help with that?